# Image is not display in repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, xml, repeater

In my website i am saving data in xml using html editor. When i add a picture before the content means on the top of the content and save it in xml.Now the problem is this that when i am trying to get result from xml to repeater control then image which is on the top of the content is giving me blank result. 
Here is the code which i am using for save data in xml

```
    int date = DateTime.Now.Day;
    int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
    int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    String File = Server.MapPath("~/Data/BlogContent.xml");
       int newid;
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(File);
        XElement root = doc.Root;
          string id = root.Elements("post").Last().ToString();
        XmlDocument pacXML = new XmlDocument();
        pacXML.Load(new StringReader(id));
        XmlNode xmlnode1;
        xmlnode1 = pacXML.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Item(1);
 String stCode = Convert.ToString(pacXML.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText).Trim();
        if (xmlnode1 == null)
        {
            newid = 1;
        }
        newid = Convert.ToInt32(stCode.ToString()) + 1;
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load(File);
        XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("content");
        XmlNode xrnode = xnode.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "post", ""));
        xrnode.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "id", "")).InnerText = newid.ToString();
        xrnode.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "title", "")).InnerText = TextBox1.Text;
        xrnode.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Discription", "")).InnerText = Editor.Text;
        xrnode.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "dt", "")).InnerText = date.ToString();
        xrnode.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "mnt", "")).InnerText = month.ToString();
        xrnode.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "yr", "")).InnerText = year.ToString();
        xrnode.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "PostDate", "")).InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        xdoc.Save(File);
        Editor.Text = string.Empty;
        TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
```

and it is the code of display data in repeater

```
PagedDataSource page = new PagedDataSource();
        page.AllowCustomPaging = true;
        page.AllowPaging = true;
        DataTable dtv = (DataTable)ViewState["Mytable"];
        DataView dv = new DataView();
        dv = dtv.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = dtv.Columns["id"].ColumnName;
        dv.Sort += " Desc";
       dv.RowFilter = "id>=" + pageSize + " AND " + "id<=" + take;
        page.DataSource = dv;
        page.PageSize = psize;
        Repeater1.DataSource = page;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int rowcount = dtv.Rows.Count;
            CreatePagingControl(rowcount);
        }
```

here repeater is binding

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
            onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" 
            onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound1" >

        <ItemTemplate>

      <ul class="articles box">
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>' color="white"></asp:Label>
         <h2><a href='<%# Eval("id","PostComment.aspx?id={0}") %>'> <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title ") %>'></asp:Label></a></h2>
             <div class="article-info box">
            <p class="f-right"><a href='<%# Eval("id","PostComment.aspx?id={0}") %>' class="comment"><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></a></p>
            <p class="f-left"> 
                Post Date:<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("postdate") %>'></asp:Label>    
          </div>
          <p>             <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="this is the blog of journeycook.com website" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
 <asp:Label ID="lblcontent" runat="server" Text='<%# Limit(Eval("Discription"),1000) %>'></asp:Label></p>
            <p class="more"><asp:HyperLink ID="ReadMoreLinkButton" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("id","~/PostComment.aspx?id={0}") %>'>Read More</asp:HyperLink></p>
           <%-- <asp:LinkButton ID="ReadMoreLinkButton" runat="server"
                Text="Read More"

                 NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("id","~/PostComment.aspx?id={0}") %>'></asp:LinkButton>--%><br /><br /><br />

       </li>
</ul>      

    </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I hope you understand what is my problem

Comment: Where is the node for the image? Where does it come from? Could you post the itemtemplate from your repeater? As an advice, you should take a look to the XDocument and XElement objects and to linq and skip and take methods as well

Comment: @Gonzix i add repeater source please check post

Comment: As I can't see any image binding and no image node in the xml I presume it's included as url or html tag within description or something similar? Do you get any error? Empty image? Do you store the image or it's just an external link?